# Can't boot into Windows 8 after boot repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

I have a Lenovo Y510P laptop and managed to get Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.10 dual booting. But then after grub was updated, I had to run boot-repair and now I can't boot into Windows.

When the computer starts and grub shows, I can boot into Ubuntu without a problem, but if I choose Windows from the boot menu, it just goes back to the menu.

I don't really know what kind of information I should provide, so please let me know if anything else besides what I posted bellow is needed.

My bios boot configuration is the following:

- Boot type: UEFI
- Secure boot: Disabled

Here is my grub.cfg file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6501866/

Here is my boot info from boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6501878/

Comment: change boot mode from UEFI to legacy mode in bios.Then ran boot-repair.

Comment: Is that the only way? It used to work in UEFI mode before.

Comment: I bought lenovo laptop z500 with preinstalled windows8 os in UEFI mode,then i change UEFI mode to legacy mode in bios.And now i had four os's in my laptop.(windows8,windows8.1,ubuntu 13.04,ubuntu 13.10)

Comment: I switched to legacy mode. Now when I run boot-repair I get this:
"EFI detected. Please check the options."
I click OK, and then I click Recommended repair, and I get this:

"GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option."

Comment: which errors you get?

Comment: I'm getting the two messages posted in my previous comment. After I click OK on the second message, I'm back at the boot-repair window.

Comment: Please run boot-repair in UEFI-mode. Maybe best to disable CSM in UEFI-settings so you can boot only in UEFI-mode and avoid this kind of confusion.